# macos screenshot without opening preview application

Tags: macos, screen-capture

Is there any way to take a screenshot without opening preview application on macOS Catelina ver. 10.15.5?

I was trying to find some information, but all I could find was about disabling Screenshot Preview Thumbnails when record a screen.
The problem what I'm facing is that the preview application is automatically opened when I take a screenshot image of screen, that I've never seen in previous version.

Could you tell me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take a screenshot on macOS Catalina, you have 3+ options. The first is pressing `Command + Shift + 3` which will screenshot the whole screen. The second `Command + Shift + 4` which will allow you to select an area to screenshot. The third is pressing `Command + Shift + 5` or typing "Screenshot" into Spotlight search. These will by default not open Preview. I did find a way that might help though. Open Screenshot or `Command + Shift + 5` and then click options and save it to another location besides Preview or whatever is selected.

Comment: OMG!!! "Open Screenshot or Command + Shift + 5 and then click options and save it to another location" helped ! The location was Quicktimeplayer before doing this, and after changing it to another location, it solved!!! I can't thank you enough.